# Check if bookmarklet is ran on the page in Chromium

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, bookmarklet

There is a web forum which I visit on daily basis where like option is implemented. When user click on the like button, bookmarklet is executed and number of likes is automatically changed. What I want to do is to track if this specific bookmarklet is ran in the browser with extension for Chromium. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Not as far as I know

Comment: @bytec0de , okay, thanks. Is it possible to check if button with defined class is clicked and get it's href parameter?

Comment: Yes, by injecting a script into the page. Probably something like this (jQuery): `$('#button').onclick(function(this) { alert($(this).attr('href')) });`

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to track if the bookmarklet has been executed unless it leaves behind some detectable change. *Since we know that the bookmarklet is executed when the user clicks the button, a workaround in this case would be to register an event listener to the like button to detect a user's click event.*